# Why is Cos[Abs[x]] Fourier transformed to 0 in mathematica?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I found that

```
FourierTransform[Cos[Abs[x]], x, ξ, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

gives `0`, while

```
FourierTransform[Cos[x], x, ξ, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

yields `π DiracDelta[-1 + ξ] + π DiracDelta[1 + ξ]`

How does this happen?

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?  I get the second answer for both statements using Windows 10, *Mathematica* 10.4.

Comment: @JimBaldwin, i'm using version 9. i'll check the new version, thanks~

Comment: @JimBaldwin, but on wolframalpha `FourierTransform[Cos[Abs[t]],t,w]` still results `0`

Comment: @andre, the second result is surely ok, but why `0` in the first one?

Comment: When I try this on v10.0, the first code returns unevaluated rather than evaluating to zero, but interestingly enough, `Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, 
 FourierTransform[Cos[Abs[x]], x, \[Xi], 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]]` returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer.

```
FourierTransform[Cos[Abs[x]], x, ξ, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
(* π DiracDelta[-1 + ξ] + π DiracDelta[1 + ξ] *)

Assuming[x ∈ Reals, FourierTransform[Cos[Abs[x]], x, ξ, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]]
(* π DiracDelta[-1 + ξ] + π DiracDelta[1 + ξ] *)

FourierTransform[Cos[x], x, ξ, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
(* π DiracDelta[-1 + ξ] + π DiracDelta[1 + ξ] *)
```

Mathematica 10.4 on Windows 10 (x64).